Knitr: combination of chunk options so a figure is not output but the code is + single figure file output
I am writing Beamer slides in Rnw using knitr. (Used to use Sweave but I just realised code looks much better in knitr.)
I like to output my figures in pdf and include them on separate slides (I have an environment that makes them completely fill a slide). Only problem: I cannot seem to find if there is a combination of chunk options that would allow me show the code but not the figure.
MWE below.
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

<<set-options,echo=FALSE,warning=FALSE,message=FALSE>>=
# Load required libraries
require(knitr)
# Knitr options
opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, 
               warning = FALSE, 
               message = FALSE, 
               fig.width = 6, 
               fig.height = 4,
               fig.keep = FALSE)
@

\begin{document}
%%
\begin{frame}[fragile]\frametitle{Frame 1}
<<test-plot-1>>=
x = 1:100
plot(x, sin(x))
@
\end{frame}
%%
\begin{frame}[fragile]\frametitle{Frame 2}
<<test-plot-2,include=FALSE>>=
plot(x, sin(x))
@
\end{frame}
%%
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Frame 3}
\includegraphics{\Sexpr{fig_chunk('test-plot-2', 'pdf')}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}


Tried a variety of combinations.. Frame 2 is always empty, whereas I would like to see the code there.
Actually, side question: is there a way to force the generation of a single figure file for a chunk? If instead of my current first chunk, I use
<<test-plot-1>>=
x = 1:100
plot(x, sin(x))
abline(h=0)
@

then I get two pdf files, test-plot-1-1.pdf and test-plot-1-2.pdf. I understand the logic (I could be making multiple plots in a chunk, in particular when "reserving" my files as I do), but it is a little frustrating to try to remember how many instructions I have issued in a plot.

I am away from my computer so I can't try this now, but one approach would be to use explicit pdf() calls to plot to file, then include those files in a later chunk. Knitr will never see the plots.  By the way knitr normally handles things like abline() fine, it's one of your chunk options that is asking for 2 plots to be shown.  Also, you can hide specific lines in a chunk by passing a numeric vector to echo= chunk options.

I have used the pdf() way in the past, I was hoping to be able to do the same thing as in sweave, where echo=TRUE,fig=TRUE,include=FALSE works. (I want to show simple code, not one including saving as pdf.) For the second part of my question: what am I using as chunk option that's triggering the two figures? That MWE is generating two figures if you substitute that second <> for the one I have in the MWE.

Sorry, still away so I can't check, but I'd guess fig.keep="high" is what you want.

... and I am sure there's a way to do what you want for echoing etc, I just forget what it is.  You should read the excellent docs at yihui.org/knitr.

I thought I had read the help,.  I think I need glasses. (Really: these letters are looking somewhat small.) That's why I came to ask. Took a second look and found it: fig.show="hide". And I confirm the fig.keep="high". Know the worst thing? I used to do that exactly in RMarkdown but somehow completely forgot when I used Sweave for several months. Should have gone back to my RMarkdown code. Thanks!
